# Jquery Function from Code Behind

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I am callilng a JQuery Function like this from VB.NET code behind, But this is not working.. Please tell me if there is any error in this Code

```
    Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "DoLogicStartup", 
    "onload =function () {DoLogic(true); GetLastDivPosition();};", True)
```

Comment: please add more info about problem, like on what you are using this, where this function is placed, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to assign the `onload` handler with `RegisterStartupScript`.  Try this instead...

```
Me.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType,
    "DoLogicStartup",  "DoLogic(true); GetLastDivPosition();", True)
```

If that doesn't work then check the browser console for errors and let us know if there's anything there.

Comment: Hi, Its working Fine Now, But can u please explain "You don't need to assign the onload handler with RegisterStartupScript". Please elaborate..

Comment: `RegisterStartupScript` places the script at the end of the page, so the document has already loaded when your script runs.  Using an `onload` handler like you were trying to do means that your code will run when the page has loaded (you were actually using it incorrectly anyway - it should have been `window.onload`).  Your code would have been placed at the end of the page and then run after everything had loaded, but still wait for the loaded event to execute before doing anything, but that had already happened.  I hope that makes sense :)